# Filter out by Company Name Attribute after successfull Azure AD Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory

> ### Background
>
> We are part of a larger Parent Company. One Azure Active Directory
> manages all of the employees of the Parent and Child companies. Our
> Web application currently uses Azure AD Authentication to authenticate
> users.
>
> ### The Problem
>
> Employees of Company A can sign into Company B's Web application when Azure AD authentication is in place
>
> ### Objective
>
> We would want to allow only Company B's employees only and it should happen after being authenticated with Azure Active Directory.
>
> ### Hint
>
> We identified that all employees being quoted their respective Company Name in the Active Directory. We feel that we could filter out and authorize our web application to employees from Company Name attribute.
>
> ### Proposed
>
> We are being proposed to use Active Directory roles and Groups. Since there is bottlenecks in managing such we just want to filter it out by Company Name attribute.

I am kind of lost as to where I can place to filter out by Company Name attribute? My confusion as to where I can start. Is it in `StartupAuth.cs` or `UserProfileController.cs` or `AccountController.cs's SignIn()`.

Please guide me how can I achieve this?

Comment: Its so easy, in `StartupAuth.cs` add [`SecurityTokenValidated`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.openidconnect.openidconnectauthenticationnotifications.securitytokenvalidated(v=vs.113).aspx) under [`OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.openidconnect.openidconnectauthenticationnotifications(v=vs.113).aspx) and have your custom logic written in it :)

Answer (score 3):

Once a user has successfully signed into your application, you will need to use the Graph API to query the properties of the signed in user.

[Basic Operations on Users](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations)

Once you have the access token for the user, you need to add a security layer between your protected application and the user. You can simply get the user object, and look at the "Company Name" attribute. If they have the company name that you want to access the site, you can allow them through. Otherwise, send them to an error page.

Querying a single user object can be found in [`UserController.cs`](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-web/blob/master/WebAppGraphAPI/Controllers/UsersController.cs)

```
        /// <summary>
        ///     Gets details of a single <see cref="User" /> Graph.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>A view with the details of a single <see cref="User" />.</returns>
        public async Task<ActionResult> Details(string objectId)
        {
            User user = null;
            try
            {
                ActiveDirectoryClient client = AuthenticationHelper.GetActiveDirectoryClient();
                user = (User) await client.Users.GetByObjectId(objectId).ExecuteAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (Request.QueryString["reauth"] == "True")
                {
                    //
                    // Send an OpenID Connect sign-in request to get a new set of tokens.
                    // If the user still has a valid session with Azure AD, they will not be prompted for their credentials.
                    // The OpenID Connect middleware will return to this controller after the sign-in response has been handled.
                    //
                    HttpContext.GetOwinContext()
                        .Authentication.Challenge(OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
                }

                //
                // The user needs to re-authorize.  Show them a message to that effect.
                //
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "AuthorizationRequired";
                return View();
            }

            return View(user);
        }
```

Comment: Hi @shawn-tabrizi I would like to get your suggention; Do I need to create an `AuthorizeAttribute` and use to all Controller action? Is there a single place where I can define this restriction, instead of assigning the `AuthorizeAttribute` to each controller's action?

Comment: @hiFI I believe you need to set the `AuthorizeAttribute` on each page where you want to force the user to be authenticated. Otherwise, the page will load when the user is signed out. If you check out our samples like [this one](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore/tree/28d2535e5675fdb0e56dc09d2791735672f54d48/TodoListService/Controllers) you will see that on the homepage, we do not force the user to authenticate, but in the todo list controller we do.

Comment: I found out rather than using `AuthorizeAttribute` I could use `SecurityTokenValidated` attribute written only in one place and no need to assign to each controller unlike `AuthorizeAttribute`

Answer (score 3):

There's a second approach you can take, as an alternative to @ShawnTabrizi's answer, which will offer more flexibility and less coding:

1. Configure the application to require assignment (under Enterprise Apps > All apps > (choose app) > Properties):

   [image: User assignment required toggle in Azure portal]
2. [Create a dynamic group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-groups-dynamic-membership-azure-portal) for Company A, by creating a filter using the `companyName` property:

   [image: Creating a dynamic group membership rule]
3. Assign the group to the app (under Enterprise Apps > All apps > (choose app) > Users and groups):

   [image: Assigning a group to an app]

Advantages:

- No coding changes. Azure AD will enforce the access control for you.
- You can assign multiple groups (or individual users) to the application.
- If your application has a concept of roles (specific to your app), you can define these app roles (in [the app manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-application-manifest)) and then assign groups or users to specific app roles. The app roles a user has been assigned to (directly or via a group) will be present as a claim in the token presented to the application, and can very easily be used for authorization decision ([sample](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-roleclaims/)).

Disadvantages:

- Requires Azure AD Premium Plan 1 for assigning groups to an app, and for dynamic groups. If you have use an alternative method to create the correct groups (users must be direct members), then you only need Azure AD Basic ([details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-editions#premium-and-basic-features)).

Comment: Hi @philippe-signoret Thank you for detail answer :)